# Do force-download responses need to be handled by angular to work? (download requested from an angular $http.post call)

Tags: angularjs, django, http, http-headers

Before adding AngularJS to my front-end I was able to download zip files from my Django server easily:

```
def myZipDownloadingView(request):
    downloadableZip = open('myZip.zip','r')
    response = HttpResponse(downloadableZip, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="myZip.zip"'
    return response
```

Now Angular is the one making a call to this view, to request the download, and the file is no longer being downloaded by the browser. Does my angular $http.post() call need to handle the response sent from the view? Can this not work simply with:

```
$http.post("myZipDownloadingView");
```

Comment: What did you use before AngularJS?

Comment: why not just submit the form through default process like you were previously doing? In other words to answer question in title...No

Comment: Before Angular I did just use the default process. My code above is slightly simplified to get the point across, but in reality I do need angular to make the request to start the download. I'll think of a better title and edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide `action` and `method` in `<form>` and don't intercept the form submit event (`ng-submit`) or the submit button event (`ng-click`) the form will submit through default browser process.

Since it is a forced download nothing else should change within state of current page

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a helpful point. But due to the nature of the page though I do need angular to make the request, as it has to take care of some processing before the request can be made. What I'm looking for is a way to make the force-download work _with_ angular.

Comment: can preprocess a form before it gets submitted if that helps.

Comment: hmm thats interesting, i'll look into that

Comment: If you intercept submit event and don't prevent the default...any modifications made within that event handler will be made prior to actual submittal. Can use ajax for downloads but requires server side changes also

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that point, I now see what you mean. So submit could happen, the angular ng-click method does its thing, and _then_ the default process kicks in. Currently I have the form on novalidate mode, so I should be able to test this just by removing that?

Comment: `ng-submit` will block default.... but you can call native `submit` on form element once the processing is done. `novalidate` just turns off html5 browser internal validation

Comment: I've tried that but it looks like the form is submitted before the angular is done processing, as if the two processes are taking place concurrently. Am I supposed to submit the form explicitly from angular, after that processing is done?